# Adding space between repeated symbol for SVG fill in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, visualisation, svg, fill

I recently learned how to perform an SVG fill for polygons. The result fills like a brick fill without spaces:

[image: e]

Is there a way to define a space between the repeated image **from within** QGIS (as opposed to editing the icon itself)? I looked all over similar SVG related questions but couldn't find how to manipulate this.

Comment: I suppose this feature is not yet available: https://issues.qgis.org/issues/16218. even if this issue is almost 5 years old. So, editing the SVG is the right choice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Chose Point Pattern Fill instead of SVG Fill, then change then "Simple Marker" to "SVG Marker". Finaly, you can change the spaces between svg symbols by clicking on Point Pattern Fill, in changing Horizontal/Vertical values under Distance.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, it worked !